# How to specify an interaction term with a lagged indep. variable and a year dummy with fixed effects regression?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction, panel-data

I would like to compute the fixed effects model in the picture: [image]

Note that first and second term of the equation is district and year fixed effects. The Third term is the interaction between a continuous variable for year = 2014 and a dummy variable for year = 2018. Last term is the error term of the regression. Im woking with a panel data frame with 3 years and 290 disctricts, so 3*290=870 observations in total.

This is what I have come up with with the package "fixest":

```
Interactionmodel <- feols(Y~ i(l(X1), Year, keep = 2018) | District + Year, panel.id = ~District+Year, data = data)
```

Is this the right way to do it? If not, please help me out. Im fine with a solution that doesnt need the package "fixest".

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Is $Z_{k2014}$ a continuous variable for all years in the panel? Or, is it a previous year not represented in your panel?

Comment: Thanks! Z is a continuous variable for all observed years in the panel (2010, 2014, 2018). Z is the a share of newly arrived immigrants for year t in district k. Where t=1,2,3 and k=1,2...,290.

Comment: Do you mean $Y_{kt}$ is the share of newly arrived immigrants, or is it $Z_{k2014}$? In your title you also allude to the presence of a lagged independent variable. Where is that in your equation?

Comment: No. $Y_{kt}$ is the share of voters that voted on a far right party in year $t$ at district $k$.
Yea sorry for the misunderstanding. I simply want to interact the variable $Z_{k2014}$ (share of newly arrived immigrants in 2014 for district $k$) with a year dummy for year 2018, i.e. $\theta Z_{k2014}*d2018$. I want to understand if the level of immigrants in 2014 had any effect on how people voted in 2018.

Comment: I can show you several ways to estimate this. First, the code you recommend interacts a past value of $Z_{k2014}$ with the 2018 time dummy. The fixed effects will absorb the 2018 effect; this isn't a problem. However, do you want $Z_{k2014}$ in the model? If you create the interaction manually (e.g., `i(z * year, keep = 2018)`), then it drops the effect for the share of newly arrived immigrants. Is this what you want? This can be done using base R, `plm` or the `fixest` packages. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I do not want to drop the effect, I think. As I said in my earlier comment, I want to understand if the "initial" level of immigration in 2014 had any effect on the election results in year 2018. Im not sure how I should approach this, so if my model is misspecified in my original post, please feel free to reply with a better approach/model and how to code this in R. Thank you a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by the "initial" level? The use of `l(.)` tells me you wanted to lag $Z$. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Hmm. Forget about the code I provided, since Im not sure its right. I want to understand if the level of immigration in the previous election year (2014) had any effect on the election results (Y) in the next election year (2018). How would you specify such a model, if my model in the original post isnt right?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Is it possible to provide a reference for that equation? I still think you want to lag $Z$, but I could be wrong. See my answer. Hopefully we can get closer to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and example code suggest you want to estimate a dynamic panel model. In particular, you noted that conservative voting patterns in district $k$ in year $t$ is explained by the share of immigrants in the previous time period (i.e., 2014). Your data is quadrennially sequenced, so the period before 2018 is 2014. The lagged version of $Z$ appears to be interacted with a 2018 time dummy. The model already includes time effects so the individual time dummy will be dropped. It shouldn't matter as the relevant information is already captured by the time effects.

In the comments you indicated that this is not a dynamic specification. I do not agree. To facilitate a better understanding of what I'm suggesting, I simulated some fake data and estimated the proposed model using three different functions. If anything is amiss I'm sure I will be corrected.

Here is a data frame with five districts observed over three time periods.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12345)

# Create our data

df <- tibble(
  district = c(rep("D1", 3), rep("D2", 3), rep("D3", 3), rep("D4", 3), rep("D5", 3)),
  year = rep(c(2010, 2014, 2018), times = 5),
  
  y_2010 = ifelse(year == 2010, 1, 0),  # 2010 time dummy
  y_2014 = ifelse(year == 2014, 1, 0),  # 2014 time dummy
  y_2018 = ifelse(year == 2018, 1, 0),  # 2018 time dummy
  
  z = runif(15, min = .25, max = .75),  # fake regressor - immigrant proportion
  y = rnorm(15, 1000, 50)               # fake outcome - conservative vote share
  ) %>%
  group_by(district) %>%                # group by district
  mutate(z_lag = dplyr::lag(z, n = 1))  # lag by 1 period
```

### lm()

```
# Base R solution
# The model includes the lagged version of z
# Only the 2018 effect is shown in the output
# The first lag means we lose a time period
# The year 2014 is the referent

> summary(lm(y ~ as.factor(district) + as.factor(year) + z_lag + I(z_lag * y_2018), data = df))$coefficients

                         Estimate Std. Error     t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)           1353.198217  239.58771  5.64802860 0.02994673
as.factor(district)D2    1.350224   76.56437  0.01763515 0.98753104
as.factor(district)D3 -146.214720   76.50061 -1.91128830 0.19612999
as.factor(district)D4   40.214273   98.30473  0.40907771 0.72212989
as.factor(district)D5   -3.174280   90.16026 -0.03520709 0.97511254
as.factor(year)2018   -354.217660  314.52739 -1.12619020 0.37705386
z_lag                 -542.999738  399.03818 -1.36077140 0.30663963
I(z_lag * y_2018)      615.698043  563.86150  1.09193134 0.38885744
```

### plm()

```
# The plm package is very useful when working with panel data
# I pre-processed the principal regressor, though plm() supports leads/lags
# This model will sweep out the fixed effects

> library(plm)
> summary(plm(y ~ z_lag + I(z_lag * y_2018), index = c("district", "year"), model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = df))$coefficients

                   Estimate Std. Error   t-value  Pr(>|t|)
z_lag             -542.9997   399.0382 -1.360771 0.3066396
I(z_lag * y_2018)  615.6980   563.8615  1.091931 0.3888574
```

#### feols()

```
# Fast Fixed-Effects Estimation
# i() is useful for interactions
# l() suggests you want to lag z by 1 period
# We easily keep 2018 to estimate the interaction

> library(fixest)
> summary(feols(y ~ z_lag + i(l(z, 1), year, keep = 2018) | district + year, panel.id = ~ district + year, data = df))$coefficients

             z_lag l(z, 1):year::2018 
         -542.9997           615.6980
```

The `feols()` function from the `fixest` package is extremely fast. Its warning messages also seem much more helpful. Note how we lose a time period by lagging $Z$.

This mirrors the example code provided in your post. I included `z_lag` in the model formula. If you didn't include the constituent term it would result in an entirely different estimate.

This should help get you going.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this Thomas! I have a follow-up question tho. How would you interpret the the coefficient of the z_lag variable and how is it different from the coefficient from the interaction term (z_lag * y_2018)? The coefficient of the interaction term is negative both when I include the variable z_lag and when I exclude it. My thinking was that it should be positive since immigration after the syria crisis in my country was through the roof - and at the same time the conservative party gained a lot of voters.